# LWJGL load image from jar with slick-util

Tags: java, image, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm creating a game with LWJGL, and I want to display the LWJGL logo when the game starts.
For that, I need to load the image from the jar file.
You can see how I set up my resources here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVo52.jpg

I have been searching, and it appears that you have to use a '/' in front of the path.
That didn't work for me, also without the '/' in front.
I also tried putting 'jar:' before resources, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream()` use `getClass.getResourceAsStream`. This will start the path from where your main class is, so you may have to use .. (it goes to the file above). Sorry if this isn't clear or I misunderstood, but this is what I did to load images in a jar.